# Custom nuxt 500 error page with preloaded state

Tags: express, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

Environment: Nuxt.js (Vue/Vuex/Node framework with SSR).

If user encounters an Internal Server Error, I want to use a custom Vue template, similar to the one I'm already using for 404 errors.

By looking at Nuxt source, it looks like the only way is to add a custom 500 page is to override the default `.nuxt/views/error.html` with my own custom error page.

I don't want just a static HTML page that the user must click out of to re-enter the app, though. I want it to still load the Nuxt app with some preloaded '500 error' state.

In Nuxt docs I don't see how to accomplish this. Any advice?

Things I have tried already:

- Redirecting from `error.html` (doesn't work because of double redirect)
- Iframe (works, but don't want to do it this way)

Comment: Answer in case anyone is still wondering: you have override the default nuxt error middleware. You can see in their GH issues, a guy who created a logging library gave a good example/base to start from.

Comment: Hi, can you give an example on how to override the nuxt error middleware?

Comment: https://nuxtjs.org/guide/views#error-page this doc don't work for you?

Comment: A decent resource for this is https://hiswe.github.io/2018/13-koa-nuxt/#Displaying-all-errors-with-Nuxt , where it describes the changes to be made to nuxt.config.js.